# Deserializing an object in a SOAP Response

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, serialization, soap

I'm trying to deserialize a SOAP response.
The soap response is like this :

```
<soapenv:Body>
      <mp0:MP0123_ConnectorRequest_001_Result>
         <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
         <mp0:result success="true">
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <mp0:actionResult type="?" aid="?">
               <mp0:success>?</mp0:success>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <mp0:errorMessage>?</mp0:errorMessage>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <mp0:dataResult>
                  <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
                  <mp0:datafield>
                     <bas:name>?</bas:name>
                     <bas:value null="false" encoding="none">?</bas:value>
                  </mp0:datafield>
               </mp0:dataResult>
            </mp0:actionResult>
         </mp0:result>
         <mp0:result-in-file>
            <bas:ticket>?</bas:ticket>
            <bas:members>
               <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
               <bas:sequence min="?" max="?"/>
               <bas:lables>
                  <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
                  <bas:fr-label aid="?">?</bas:fr-label>
               </bas:lables>
            </bas:members>
         </mp0:result-in-file>
      </mp0:MP0123_ConnectorRequest_001_Result>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

The classes generated from WSDL are like this:

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://schemas.datastream.net/MP_results/MP0123_001")]
    public partial class MP0123_ConnectorRequest_001_Result {

        private object itemField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("result", typeof(MP0123_ConnectorRequest_001_ResultResult))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("result-in-file", typeof(fileResult))]
        public object Item {
            get {
                return this.itemField;
            }
            set {
                this.itemField = value;
            }
        }
    }

   /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://schemas.datastream.net/MP_results/MP0123_001")]

public partial class MP0123_ConnectorRequest_001_ResultResult {

private MP0123_ConnectorRequest_001_ResultResultActionResult[] actionResultField;

private bool successField;

public MP0123_ConnectorRequest_001_ResultResult() {
    this.successField = true;
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("actionResult")]
public MP0123_ConnectorRequest_001_ResultResultActionResult[] actionResult {
    get {
        return this.actionResultField;
    }
    set {
        this.actionResultField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute(true)]
public bool success {
    get {
        return this.successField;
    }
    set {
        this.successField = value;
    }
}
```

}

Now I get the response by the following code, but as the only thing that I have is Response.Item which is an object I cannot deserialize it.

```
var response = connector.ConnectorRequestOp(Request);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConnectorRequest_001_ResultResult),"http://schemas.datastream.net/MP_results/MP0123_001");
var  responseREsult = (MP0123_ConnectorRequest_001_ResultResult)serializer.Deserialize(new MemoryStream(response.Item));
```

I know that I cannot use `MemoryStream` in this case, so I searched a lot and read the similar posts here, but the only possible way I found was to use the path and use `FileStream` but I don't have the response path (I think). So is there any way to deserialize an object ?

I don't know if I miss some important concepts in serialize/deserialize an soap response, as it's my first time dealing with this.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to deserialize it manually, just use proxy class generated.

Comment: You mean just cast it as the class and that's it?

Comment: Just call your methods. they will return the appropriate object.

Comment: no it doesn't. I editted the code as you see it returns an response with a property name Item which has two XMLAttribute for Result and result-in-file that between two I need to get the result. and I think need to deserialize the Item to get the Result

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the result as follows:

```
var response = connector.ConnectorRequestOp(Request);

if(response != null && response.Item != null)
{
    if(response.Item Is MP0123_ConnectorRequest_001_ResultResult)
    {
        var responseResult = response.Item As MP0123_ConnectorRequest_001_ResultResult;
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        var otherResult = response.Item As fileResult
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It has two attribute with two different types which one of them is `MP0123_ConnectorRequest_001_ResultResult`, with this consideration can I do that?